# realm java - bulk update on RealmResults or RealmQuery

Tags: java, realm

In Realm ObjC it is possible to perform update operation on RLMResults collection like this:

```
RLMResults<Pubs *> *pubsToDelete = [Pubs objectsWhere: @"NOT (pubId IN %@)", apiIds];

[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
   // all pubs in pubsToDelete will be updated 
   [pubsToDelete setValue:@YES forKeyPath:@"deleted"];
}];
```

Is it possible also in Java version or I have to perform iteration over RealmResults and set the value for each object? Like

```
RealmResults<Pubs> results = query.findAll();

realm.beginTransaction();
for (Pubs p : results) {
    p.deleted = 1;
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Realm-Java you need to iterate for all objects.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Pubs> results = query.findAll();
        for(Pub p : results) {
            p.deleted = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i thought it, thanks. generally it seems that realm java is weaker than realm objc, also due lack of predicates etc

Comment: Yeah, Realm-Java is younger and had to fix more system-specific quirks (and now with the Object Store integration, they have even more of them to fix) - but a batch update like that would be quite nice for Realm-Java, it's much more memory-efficient that way.